# Windows 10 My trash takes ages and then does not open

Tags: windows-10, trash

When I try to open my trash it doesn't let me, but I suspect I accidentally deleted some stuff.  It gets to about 95% and just keeps loading forever.

Is there a way I can see what's in the trash using a different method?  I'd like to clear it but I don't want to yet because I'm worried I have things I need in there.

I have tried using the command line as administrator to enter the recycle bin as suggested in one of the answers.  Here was the result.  The correct recycle bin for my user is the longer of the two folder names.

[image: CMD as administrator]

As you can see there is only one file desktop.ini but a lot of filesize which indicates part of the puzzle is missing.

Comment: Have you checked your Event Viewer to see what errors the system reports while trying to open the Recycle Bin?

Comment: I'm not certain what's causing the problem, but it may be worth running CHKDSK overnight.  Leave some time in the morning before you need to use it again, to review errors or read results.

Comment: I didn't even know about event viewer so I'll try that. And then do CHKDSK. Thanks both

Comment: So the short one SID folder is the default user account from which others account profile folders are created when an account is logged into for the first time. No need to even touch that. The longer one is the one you're looking for, and the fact it comes up essentially empty indicates it is either corrupted itself, or it traverses some dead parts on your hard drive. Have you run Checkdisk? Is your drive HDD or SSD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view the contents of the Recycle Bin in the command prompt. Start by opening Command (not PowerShell), then enter the following, hitting Return after each line

```
C:
```

This will take you to your C drive.

```
cd \$Recycle.Bin
```

The Recycle Bin is a hidden directory. It will only show up when you type `dir /a:h` to show hidden files and folders.

Inside the `$Recycle.Bin` folder there are several directories which are also hidden. These are named for the GUID/SID of the accounts on your computer. You can only access the one belonging to your own account, so you may need to check each in turn.

Use `tab` to autocomplete a `CD S-` command to check each folder. Folders not belonging to you will return `Access is denied.` Your own Recycle Bin directory will allow you in. Once you've found your Recycle Bin folder and entered it, enter:

```
dir /a:h
```

This will show all the files in your Recycle Bin and allow you to tell whether any of the files need to be restored before emptying the Recycle Bin.

You should be able to retrieve the files by using `mv` (move) or `copy` commands. You'll also need to reset the Hidden attribute on these files in order to see them in their new locations in your File Explorer.

**However...**

The Recycle Bin failing to open is a problem you MUST investigate. This could mean your Hard Drive is failing and folders in the Recycle Bin cross bad sectors. It could mean corruption on the disk and you should run Check Disk to try to find and repair this.

The Recycle Bin failing to open is the REAL problem here, and it could be serious so you should check into it soon to prevent it from becoming worse.

**Update: OP Solved**

OP notes the cause of these symptoms in their case was that the drive was out of space, and the Recycle Bin was using a significant portion of that space.

Once they were able to clear space in this drive, they were able to access the Recycle Bin and its contents successfully.

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer. I've down as you suggest but it doesn't show much. Even if I navigate into the only directories it will allow I eventually get a message volume is in drive C has no label. Serial number is xxxx. Directory of xxx file not found

Comment: Prior to that I get . and .. and 129

Comment: You're seeing that inside your S-1-... recycle bin directory?

Comment: Yes. I see one directory and no files. Just the number 129

Comment: Is 129 a directory? Can you enter it?

Comment: All relevant information required to answer your question should be contained in the question body, not a comment to an answer.

Comment: Eoin, the way to put more information into the original question is to click on the grey `edit` link underneath the line of tags. It will take you to https://superuser.com/posts/1359606/edit .  We've already got six replies which could, and should, be moved into the body of the original question to update it. After you move a reply's content into the original post, please also click on the faint grey (X) following the comment to remove the comment, for a lot of comments make it difficult to understand what's going on.

Comment: Do not run cmd as admin. Your own user context already has the permissions necessary to view and manage your own Recycle Bin, and because that also means you cannot accidentally access another's Recycle Bin, it keeps things simpler too.

Comment: Thanks all, very helpful.  Updated as per the advice.  I left some comments so the other comments made sense and move relevant ones to the question.  If I can do anything else to make this answer more helpful please say.

Comment: This was caused by an overly full SSD and a very full trash can.  Once I made space things started working again.  Thanks for all your help.  Can you edit your answer and add that information too and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Updated as requested. I'm glad you were able to find the solution. I don't know if you're knew this, but if you want to delete a file skipping the Recycle Bin (ie, you KNOW the file can go away and you need the space immediately) holding the SHIFT key and then pressing DEL will skip the Recycle Bin and completely delete the file. This can be handy in situations like yours where the Recycle Bin is full and you're out of space on the drive.